# TypeScript, error in tsconfig.json when importing module from self-made package

Tags: typescript

I need to share some functions between Node projects, so I created a private repository in my Github account, then I added it to a new project with:

```
$ yarn add git+ssh://git@github.com:my_gh/my-api-types.git --dev
```

I can see the code in **node_modules/my-api-types** directory and I can import the code with:

```
import { AccountResolvers } from "my-api-types";
```

VS Code doesn't send any error message and actually the IDE display properly the methods inside AccountResolvers. But when I want to compile the project I'm getting:

```
ERROR in /home/manuel/customer-service/tsconfig.json
[tsl] ERROR
    TS6307: File '/home/manuel/customer-service/node_modules/my-api-types/src/features/account/account.graphql.ts' 
    is not in project file list. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.
```

The error address to my **tsconfig.json** but I've being using the same file with other projects without problem:

```
  {
   "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "es2016",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "outDir": "./dist/",
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "jsx": "react",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
     "noImplicitReturns": true,
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
     "strict": true,
     "noUnusedLocals": true
   }
 }
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is gone when the option "composite" is set as "false", the help doc says:

Referenced projects must have the new `composite` setting enabled. This setting is needed to ensure TypeScript can quickly determine where to find the outputs of the referenced project. Enabling the `composite` flag changes a few things:

- The `rootDir` setting, if not explicitly set, defaults to the directory containing the`tsconfig` file
- All implementation files must be matched by an `include` pattern or listed in the `files` array. If this constraint is violated, `tsc` will inform you which files weren’t specified
- `declaration` must be turned on

Comment: Did you ever find a solution using composite=true?

Comment: You are allowed to self answer, so if you could please post the update as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In `tsconfig.json` set composite=true

Referenced projects must have the new composite setting enabled.

This setting is needed to ensure TypeScript can quickly determine where to find the outputs of the referenced project. Enabling the composite flag changes a few things:

When this setting is on: >>>

- The rootDir setting, if not explicitly set, defaults to the directory containing the tsconfig.json file.
- **All implementation files must be matched by an include pattern or listed in the files array. If this constraint is violated, tsc will inform you which files weren’t specified.**
- declaration defaults to true

[source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#composite)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.